# Bean Validation Message with dynamic parameter

Tags: validation, jakarta-ee, message, bean-validation

I am getting started with bean validation, and I'm trying to compose a constraint. My constraint is to validate a CPF(personal document in Brazil). My constraint is working, but I need the message to contain a dynamic parameter.

I'm using ValidationMessages.properties. My code:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy=CpfValidator.class)
@Size(min=11, max=14)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Cpf {

    String message() default "{cpf.validation.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

My ValidationMessages.properties:

```
cpf.validation.message=Cpf {cpf} é inválido
```

My Validator: i'm using a context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate to customiza my message.

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    String cpf = value;

    boolean result = ValidationUtil.validaCpf(cpf);
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }

    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("pf.validation.message}")
           .addConstraintViolation();
    return false;

}
```

How can I pass the validated value(cpf) by parameter when the message is created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When working with Hibernate Validator >= 4.2 you can reference the validated value via `${validatedValue}` in your messages (in Bean Validation 1.1 that's standardized in the spec):

```
cpf.validation.message=Cpf ${validatedValue} é inválido
```

Btw. Hibernate Validator already comes with a `@CPF` constraint, you can find out more in the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints). Would be very glad to hear about how that works for you.

Comment: Thank's for your help Gunnar, but I can't use annotations that are not JPA specification.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution, i think i can improve that solution, but for now it's good. I did this changes in my code:

```
String message() default "Cpf %s é inválido";

String msgDefault = context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate();
String msgFormatada = String.format(msgDefault, cpf);

context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(msgFormatada).addConstraintViolation();
```

Answer (score 7):

if we want to provide other parameter instead of the validated value to the message:

```
cpf.validation.message=Cpf {cpf} é inválido
```

We can use HibernateConstraintValidatorContext as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    String cpf = value;

    boolean result = ValidationUtil.validaCpf(cpf);
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }

    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
    hibernateContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    hibernateContext
           .addMessageParameter( "cpf", cpf )
           .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("pf.validation.message}")
           .addConstraintViolation();

    return false;

}
```

As is mentioned above, is in hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-hibernateconstraintvalidatorcontext)